# How to restart dask worker subprocess after task is done?

Tags: dask, distributed, dask-distributed

In django-q we have `recycle` which is `The number of tasks a worker will process before recycling . Useful to release memory resources on a regular basis.`

When I start dask-worker with --nprocs 2, I get two worker subprocesses.

I would like to recycle them after each of them complete 1 task because there are a lot of resources that need to be freed and removed from memory after task is complete and I have no way of freeing them in an automatic fashion.

I tried a worker plugin with a simple `sys.exit()` inside `release_key` but it doesn't get rid of the process.

How to recycle worker subprocesses after task is done?